# is it possible to collect comment data form multiple zip files without unzipping?

Tags: python, zip

Hello is it possible to collect the comment data of a zip file from multiple files?(as the optional comment you get on the side when opening a Zip or a Rar file)

and if so, where exactly does the comment gets stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

zipfiles = ["example.zip",]
for zfile in zipfiles:
    print("Opening: {}".format(zfile))
    with ZipFile(zfile, 'r') as testzip:
        print(testzip.comment) # comment for entire zip
        l = testzip.infolist() #list all files in archive
        for finfo in l:
            # per file/directory comments
            print("{}:{}".format(finfo.filename, finfo.comment))
```

Check http://www.artpol-software.com/ZipArchive/KB/0610242300.aspx for more information on how and where metadata is stored in zip files.